# VSTS link build definition version numbers

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, build-definition

We're using VSTS to manage our repositories and as a build manager.
We have a solution with multiple assemblies, where one of the assemblies is packaged as NuGet package to be referenced by other projects.

We have 2 build definitions. One definition for the entire solution to both create a deployable package and the NuGet package, and one definition to only create a NuGet package.

The versioning:

- The version number is like {Major}.{Minor}.{Build}.{Revision}
- Everytime Solution definition gets built, the Build should be incremented
- Everytime NuGet definition gets built, the Revision should be incremented

E.G.:

- Start with 1.0.5(.0)
- NuGet gets built => 1.0.5.1
- Solution gets built => 1.0.6(.0)
- Solution gets built => 1.0.7(.0)
- NuGet gets built => 1.0.7.1
- NuGet gets built => 1.0.7.2
- etc

To accomplish this, we're using the $(rev:.r) variable in the build definition, which increments at every build. 
However, in the NuGet definition we don't know what the latest build number is in the Solution definition.

Currently we're using a variable to set it, but as you can imagine, this is not desirable.
The question is, can we somehow link the NuGet definition to the Solution definition to extract the Build number?

Comment: You're making this much more difficult than it needs to be.  I can see no benefit in linking your nuget versions to your solution versions, this is just going to be a mess to manage properly.  I'd use GitVersion in both your nuget package and solution and be done with it!

Answer (score 0):

It’s unreasonable to use build number for package version. Reasons as below:

1. Build number is the same in a build.
2. Build number will be increased for all the build definitions across your VSTS account. Such as when you build definition1 in project1, the build number is 100. Then if the build definition2 in project2 is build, the build number will be 101. And if you build deinition1 after that, the build number will be 102.

And the common ways to set nuget package versions is using gitversion or assembly version:

If you are using git as VCS, and the workflow comply with the [gitflow of gitversion](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/git-branching-strategies/gitflow/), then you can use [**GitVersion**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gitversion) task, and use the version variable which generate by this task as nuget package version.

Or you can use [**Update AssemblyInfo**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sebastianlux.UpdateAssemblyInfo) task or [**Assembly Info Reader**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kherzog.AssemblyInfoReader) task etc for the nuget package version.

Comment: I didn't mean the build number in VSTS. As said, we're using the $(rev:.r) variable, which increments for every build within a build definition. Anyway, I'll give the GitVersion a try, Thanks!

Comment: `$(rev:.r)` will also increase for the same build definition. And if you have problems using GitVersion for nuget package version feel free to show the problem.